# Adding Class For the Last Row elememts in a listing

Tags: jquery, css, xhtml

```
<ul class="list_availability">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
```

That will result like this with styles 3 `<li>` in each row

```
|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|
| | | |

|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|
| | |

|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|
| |
```

I want to add a class (with jQuery) for `<li>`'s in the last row even    it has both 3, 2, 1 item

---

*attempted clarification...*

The CSS lays out the `<li>` elements in such a way that there are 3 per row.

The problem is that the total number of `<li>` elements is not always evenly divisible by `3`, so the last row could have `1`, `2`, or `3` elements.

What I'm trying to do is add a class to the `<li>`s in just the last row. How can I target just those elements when I don't know how many there will be?

Comment: -1 - question vague and badly written.  What is the problem you are trying to solve and what problem are you having?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Comment: I understood the question, and I think I've a solution below. No need to downvote on questions you don't understand ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will probably need to count something like this:

```
lastRowItemsCount = ($("ul.list_availability li").length % 3);
if (lastRowItemsCount == 0) lastRowItemsCount = 3;
$("ul.list_availability li").slice(-lastRowItemsCount).addClass("lastRow");​
```

this will add an class to the items in last row only.

you just need to handle if there is less than 3 items. But that will be pretty easy, right? ;)

You can test it here by adding or removin `<li>` items:
http://jsfiddle.net/7bx6v/2/

Comment: This would be my best guess at what's wanted, but you need to replace `MOD` with `%`.

Comment: Here's some style on your jsFiddle to make it a little clearer. http://jsfiddle.net/8gBTe/

Answer (score 1):

```
$("ul.list_availability li:last").addClass("last");
```

Comment: because he wants ALL elements in the last row beeing added a class

Answer (score 0):

Eh?

```
$("ul li").slice(-3).addClass("foo");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7bx6v/